# map of pointers to functions of different return types and signatures

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-asio, function-pointers

I am looking for a way to call different functions by a string input.

I have a map that ties each unique string to a function pointer and a lookup function to search the map and return a pointer if found.

Now the trick is, I need a way to store and return pointers to functions with at least different return types, if possible, also with different signatures.

The usage would be:

Get a string input from a network socket -> 
find and execute the found function -> shove the result straight back into the socket to be serialized and sent, not caring what actually happened.

Is this doable? If not, how would one approach this task?

Comment: what about making the return type of the function "serialized result"(vector of chars for example) of the function to make function sigs same?

Comment: Yeah, that would be one option. I had a problem with freestanding integers (which will be sent for sure) while considering this approach but that is another issue, I guess.

Comment: wish I could help you with that, but tbh I dont understand what the problem with freestanding integers is. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can be done with a bit of boilerplate code in different ways. If the number of signatures is small enough you can hold multiple vectors of function pointers (one per function type) and then a map that maps the function name with a type identifier (used to select the vector) and the position within the vector.

The second option would be to store a `boost::variant` (again, if the set of signatures is small). You would need to provide a visitor object that evaluates the function (for each function type stored) and yields the result. The type is managed by the `boost::variant` type so there would be no need for the type tag to be stored in the map.

You can also use full type erasure and store in the map a tag determining the type of function to be called and a `boost::any` object storing the function pointer. You can use the type information to retrieve the pointer and execute the function, but you will have to manually handle the `switch` based on function type.

The simplest approach, on the other hand, is to write adapters that have a fixed interface. Then just store the pointers to the adapters in the map.

Answer (score 2):

While you can't store *different* function pointers, you can store objects which contain those functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Functor{
public:
    template<class T>
    void operator()(T data){}
};
template<class T>
class BaseFunctor : public Functor{
public:
    virtual void CallFunction(T data){ }
};
class FunctionPointer1 : public BaseFunctor<void *>{
public:
    void doFunction1(){
        cout << "Do Function 1"<<endl;
    }
    template<class T>
    void CallFunction(T data){ doFunction1(); }
    template<class T>
    void operator()(T data){ this->CallFunction(data); }
};

class FunctionPointer2 : public BaseFunctor<int>{
public:
    void doFunction2(int variable){ cout << "Do function 2 with integer variable" << variable <<endl; }
    template<class T>
    void CallFunction(T data) { doFunction2(data);} 
    template<class T>
    void operator()(T data){ this->CallFunction(data); }
};

class FunctionPerformer{
    private:
       map<string,Functor> functions;
    public:
       FunctionPerformer(){
         //init your map.
            FunctionPointer1 function1;
        FunctionPointer2 function2;
            //-- follows
        functions["Function1"] = function1;
        functions["Functions2"] = function2;
            //-- follows
       }
       Functor getFunctionFromString(string str){
                return functions[str]
       }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    map<string,Functor> functions;
    FunctionPerformer performer;

    Functor func1, func2; // to hold return values from perfomer()
    FunctionPointer1 *fn1; // to casting and execute the functions
    FunctionPointer2 *fn2; // to casting and execute the functions
    func1 = performer.getFunctionFromString("Function1");//get data
    func2 = performer.getFunctionFromString("Function2");

    //following two lines to cast the object and run the methods
    fn1 = reinterpret_cast<FunctionPointer1 *>(&func1);
    (*fn1)(NULL);

    //following two lines to cast the object and run the methods
    fn2 = reinterpret_cast<FunctionPointer2 *>(&func2);
    (*fn2)(10);

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I think the edited part makes it clearer?
This code can be optimized a little. Play around with it.

Comment: How would I make a lookup for such a thing?

Comment: @jt234 you don't have to. The map<> takes care of it for you.

Comment: How would I write a function that took in a string and executed a function? Your example contains a fair amount of hardcoded info. My goal would be: `runFuncByName(string cmd)`

Comment: Yeah, I understand what happens there. My problem is that the reinterpret cast still stays constant. The program wouldn't know which one is needed if I need only one function, would it? The calls will be coming from a different machine altogether.

Comment: You will need a little more if() conditions to know which one to execute. Sadly, C++ is too "strict" when it comes to "types". The only way around is to use such hacks/tricks.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable in C++11 with Variadic Templates. Check my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33837343/1496826

Answer (score 0):

No, it's really not doable, you need a real interpreted language if you want to do something like this. As soon as the signature is not constant then you need something a lot more involved.

Comment: Ok, I could just go with different return types. As far as I know, return types are not part of the signature for non-template functions. Would only that be possible?

Comment: I have a way around this. I will be posting in a bit

Answer (score 0):

How about making all those functions have the same signature? You could make all return types implement an interface, or use a collection, class, union or struct. Same for the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use specialization and templates to work around the issue?

```
template <class T>
T FooBar(void * params);

template<> int FooBar<int>( void * params ); 

template<> char FooBar<char>( void * params );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the function pointers themselves, which are too different from one another to be accommodated into the same data structure, you can store adaptors that take care of bridging the mismatch. This is a form of type-erasure. An example:

```
// Imaginary important resources
blaz_type get_blaz();
qux_type get_qux();

// The functions we'd like to put in our map
int foo(blaz_type);
std::string bar(qux_type);

using context_type = std::tuple<blaz_type, qux_type>;
using callback_type = std::function<void(context_type, socket_type&)>;

using std::get;
std::map<std::string, callback_type> callbacks = {
    {
        "foo"
         , [](context_type context, socket_type& out)
           { marshall(out, foo(get<0>(std::move(context)))); }
    }
    , {
        "bar"
        , [](context_type context, socket_type& out)
          { marshall(out, bar(get<1>(std::move(context)))); }
    }
};
```

In this example the adaptors are not stateful so you can actually use `void (*)(context_type, socket_type&)` as the `callback_type`.

Do note that this kind of design is a bit brittle in that the `context_type` needs to know about *every* kind of parameter a stored callback might ever need. If at some later point you need to store a callback which needs a new kind of parameter, you need to modify `context_type` -- if you improve the above design *not* to use magic numbers like `0` and `1` as parameters to `std::get` you could save yourself some pains (especially in the reverse situation of removing types from `context_type`). This is not an issue if all callbacks take the same parameters, in which case you can dispense yourself with the `context_type` altogether and pass those parameters to the callbacks directly.

[Demonstration on LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/ec17918ba9bd68aafc16e8df99a3e363).

Comment: This is by no means the only way to go about it. This answer is not definitive and it's recommended to take a peek at the others.