# How to call class function dynamically by string

Tags: c++

I am wondering how can I dynamically call class functions. Let's say I have a class '"dog", which contains function getname(),  that returns name of that specific animal. But how could I call function dog::getname() like that but without the "dog" at the beginning I would use std::string animal = "dog", and then somehow do like animal::getname()

I haven't tried anything yet, because I simply have no idea how I could get similar result, or if it's even possible.

```
class dog {
public:
   static std::string getname() {
      return "Something";
   }
}

class cat {
public:
   static std::string getname() {
      return "Something2";
   }
}

std::string animal = "dog";
```

And now somehow call the function getname related to the animal which is in the string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add reflection to a C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application)

Comment: How can a function that's declared as returning nothing (`void`) return something?

Comment: My bad, shoud be an type of sting.

Comment: Hint: It's C++. You can't really dynamically call anything, it's not a dynamic language. You can make a dispatcher function, you can use preprocessing, but you can't really call arbitrary functions based on string names.

Comment: If you can store these properties as a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` then you could have a generic `get(const std::string& name)` accessor and special ones like `getName() { return property["name"] }`

Comment: Your example with using a `std::string animal` makes no sense since that's a string and it will never respond to `getname()`.

Comment: Is the string an absolute necessity or is it part of an incomplete solution to the real problem? This might be an XY-problem. I think you're looking for virtual functions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for polymorphism?

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

// An animal interface for all animals to implement
class Animal {
public:
    virtual ~Animal() = default;

    virtual std::string getName() const = 0;
};

// An implementation of the animal interface for dogs
class Dog final : public Animal {
public:
   std::string getName() const override {
      return "John";
   }
};

// An implementation of the animal interface for cats
class Cat final : public Animal {
public:
   std::string getName() const override {
      return "Angelina";
   }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Animal> animal0 = std::make_unique<Dog>();
    std::unique_ptr<Animal> animal1 = std::make_unique<Cat>();
    // You can pass around a std::unique_ptr<Animal> or Animal *
    // just as you would pass around a string.
    // Although, std::unique_ptr is move-only
    std::cout << animal0->getName() << '\n';
    std::cout << animal1->getName() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ itself doesn't provide reflection, which would let you do this easily -- the class names are stripped away during compilation.

If you really want to call different functions based on a string name, you'd have to store the mapping from the names to the function pointers and use it to invoke the function you want.

Depending on your specific use-case you could do this by hand (see [Using a STL map of function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136998/using-a-stl-map-of-function-pointers)) or use more sophisticated solutions from the thread someone already linked to: [How can I add reflection to a C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application)

Comment: As @Kaz mentioned in the comments, the question itself is a possible duplicate.

Comment: Obviously, I disagree that this is an exact duplicate of that question. I also feel the other question is too unspecific.

Comment: It's about the concept of 'reflection' in C++, That'swhy I mentioned in the comment as duplicate. I agree with the unspecific nature of the other question.