# C++: How to create a member unordered_map with values of pointers to functions

Tags: c++, c++14

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136998/using-a-stl-map-of-function-pointers) answers how to do it for a regular `unordered_map`, but what about the member one? The IDE reports the error in the comment. `opcodes` maps characters to pointers to functions, which should be called on behalf of concrete instances. Also I wonder if it's possible to make it constexpr.

```cpp
// Foo.cpp

class Foo {
public:
    void execute(char c) { (*opcodes[c])(); }

    void operation1()
    {
        // Do something with value_
    }

    void operation2();

private:
    typedef void (*operation)();

    static const std::unordered_map<char, operation> opcodes{
            {'1', &Foo::operation1},
            {'2', &Foo::operation2}
    }; // No matching constructor for initialization of 'const std::unordered_map<char, operation>' (aka 'const unordered_map<char, void (*)()>')
    int value_;
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.execute('1');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `operation` type is right? Hint: *pointer to function* and *pointer to member function* are not the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to create a member unordered_map with values of pointers to functions?

Like this:

```
struct example {
    using fun = return_type(/*arg types*/);
    std::unordered_map<key_type, fun*> map;
};
```

---

> ```
> typedef void (*operation)();
> static const std::unordered_map<char, operation> opcodes{
>         {'1', &Foo::operation1},
>         {'2', &Foo::operation2}
> }
> ```

The problem with this is that you have a map of pointers function, but you try to initialise with pointers to member functions. A pointer to member function is not a pointer to function and cannot be converted to a pointer to function.

So, what you need is a map of pointers to member functions instead:

```
using operation = void (Foo::*)();
```

Or, you need to not be using non-static member functions.

---

> And how to call the [pointer to member] function after getting it from map?

Example:

```
(this->*opcodes.at('1'))();
```

Comment: So the problem is that I use non-static functions in a static context, and the solution is to create an external structure which will do the mapping by itself?

Comment: @kenticent I've added two alternative solutions to the answer.

Comment: And how to call the function after getting it from map? I suspect ```(*opcodes.at('1'))()``` won't work (it doesn't).

Comment: @kenticent I added an example.

Comment: Thanks for a profound answer, figured it out just before you wrote)