# C++ Map of string and member function pointer

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointer-to-member

Hey so I am making a map with string as the key and a member function pointer as the value. I can't seem to figure out how to add to the map, this doesn't seem to be working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

typedef string(Test::*myFunc)(string);
typedef map<string, myFunc> MyMap;


class Test
{
private:
    MyMap myMap;

public:
    Test(void);
    string TestFunc(string input);
};





#include "Test.h"

Test::Test(void)
{
    myMap.insert("test", &TestFunc);
    myMap["test"] = &TestFunc;
}

string Test::TestFunc(string input)
{
}
```

Comment: A guess, but `&Test::TestFunc`?

Comment: Seems to fix one error in the parameters, but I still get an error for insert

Comment: @Kosmo That's because `insert` doesn't work that way.

Comment: What does "this doesn't seem to be working" mean?

Comment: The insert said there no instance of the overloaded function and the [] assignment sais it must be a modifiable value

Comment: Be specific, quote the errors. Concerning insert(), you must convert it to the correct type, which is a pair<T1 const, T2>, aka map::value_type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::map of member function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924844/stdmap-of-member-function-pointers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) and [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) for `value_type`

```
myMap.insert(std::map<std::string, myFunc>::value_type("test", &Test::TestFunc));
```

and for `operator[]`

```
myMap["test"] = &Test::TestFunc;
```

You cannot use a pointer to member function without an object. You can use the pointer to member function with an object of type `Test`

```
Test t;
myFunc f = myMap["test"];
std::string s = (t.*f)("Hello, world!");
```

or with a pointer to type `Test`

```
Test *p = new Test();
myFunc f = myMap["test"];
std::string s = (p->*f)("Hello, world!");
```

See also [C++ FAQ - Pointers to member functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)

Comment: +1, although because `std::map<A,B>::value_type` is `pair<const A,B>` I prefer to insert `MyMap::value_type(a, b)` not `std::make_pair(a,b)` otherwise you get `pair<A,B>` which has to be converted to `pair<const A,B>` and that conversion cannot be elided.

Comment: I'm just wondering whether passing a string literal to make_pair is supposed to work? After all, the implied template type there is char[5], not std::string or somesuch.

Comment: @doomster, it's _const_ `char[5]`, and in C++03 `make_pair` takes its arguments by value, so the array decays to a pointer in the argument list, and in C++11 the  return type uses std::decay<const char[5]>::type` which also decays to a pointer. So it works perfectly.

Comment: @doomster You're right, this will be a `std::pair<const char*, ...>` and not `std::pair<std::string, ...>`. Although it works, Jonathan Wakely's version should be preferred.

Comment: Thanks got it, when trying to call the function with the key I'm having trouble, I tried:
convertFunc fu = converters[input]; or
map<string, convertFunc>::const_iterator it = converters.find(converter); and
return fu(input); or
return (*fu)(input);

Comment: Also, if you're trying to do this with a non-static function you can do this black magic `(this->*f)("Hello World")`